# Shuffle two arrays non-randomly

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have two different arrays with arrays in them:

```
Vowels = [['a', 'a'], ['a', 'e'], ['a', 'i']]
Consonants = [['b', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'c'], ['b', 'b', 'd']]
```

I want to be able to mix them together into every possible combination, without losing or adding content, with a function

```
allmixes(Vowels, Consonants)
#=> [['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], ['a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'a'], ...]
```

By mix, I mean that I need the two arrays two have a sort of combination without duplicates, or a shuffle that follows a pattern letting me call a certain result by index.

Answer (score 1):

```
Vowels = [['a', 'a'], ['a', 'e']]
Consonants = [['b', 'b', 'b'], ['b', 'b', 'c']]

Vowels.product(Consonants).flat_map { |v,c| (v+c).permutation.to_a.uniq }
  #=> [["a", "a", "b", "b", "b"], ["a", "b", "a", "b", "b"], ["a", "b", "b", "a", "b"],
       ["a", "b", "b", "b", "a"], ["b", "a", "a", "b", "b"], ["b", "a", "b", "a", "b"],
       ["b", "a", "b", "b", "a"], ["b", "b", "a", "a", "b"], ["b", "b", "a", "b", "a"],
       ["b", "b", "b", "a", "a"], ["a", "a", "b", "b", "c"], ["a", "a", "b", "c", "b"],
       ["a", "a", "c", "b", "b"], ["a", "b", "a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "a", "c", "b"],
       ... 
       ["c", "b", "a", "e", "b"], ["c", "b", "a", "b", "e"], ["c", "b", "e", "a", "b"],
       ["c", "b", "e", "b", "a"], ["c", "b", "b", "a", "e"], ["c", "b", "b", "e", "a"]] 

Vowels.product(Consonants).flat_map { |v,c| (v+c).permutation.to_a.uniq }.size
  #=> 120
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `permutation`:

```
vowels.flat_map do |vowel|
  consonants.flat_map do |consonant|
    [*vowel,*consonant].permutation.to_a.uniq
  end
end
```

[**Demonstration**](https://repl.it/Drgc)

Comment: If I set `vowels = Vowels` and `consonants = Consonants`, for `Vowels` and `Consonants` defined in my answer, your code produces the same array (of 120 elements) that I get with my code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: i am sorry, what is your point (sleep hazard)?

Comment: Just that we're either both right or both wrong. 

Comment: @CarySwoveland: gotcha 